# Is it possible to have disjoint nested views in marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

So basically what I'm trying to do is to have a layoutView and inside that layoutView have a subview that is wrapped with the layoutView. The catch is that layoutView should also render information from model.

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLODv.png

So far, I didn't have any joy or success in achieving this, because it seems to me that views are somehow unitary and homogeneous, ergo can't be disjoint

For the layoutView I'd have following template:

```
<div id="someLayoutView">
    Hi, <%= userName %>
    <div id = "someRegion"></div>
    <div>Some other information needed from model: <%= someVariable %></div>
</div>
```

with #someRegion showing the subView.

Is this possible or is there any similar approach to achieve this kind of nesting/wrapping views?

Comment: All I gather from the way you worded your question is that you're having trouble carrying out the fundamental purpose of a LayoutView, rendering a subview within a LayoutView region. Please, clarify the problem. And, in particular, please explain why you can't do `someRegion.show(someSubView)`. Please, read http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.layoutview.html#basic-usage

Comment: There should be no problems here. LayoutView inherits from ItemView so you should be able to access your LayoutView model in your template. Then just pass the LayoutView model to your subview and do the same there.